# Using Ajax get Byte Image and show Image on client site in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I convert image to byte and now I want to byteImage to show Image in the browser, how can I do that. I have get only two data one is Image **ID** and another is  **Image_name**  and show in table ,but I can't show Image in table

Model:

```
   public class ImageFile
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Image_Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageInbyte { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        public JsonResult GetAllImageList()
        {
            var allImage_List = _imageManager.GetAll();
            return Json(allImage_List, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Get Json Request Data:

```
[{"ID":1,"Image_Name":"test","ImageInbyte":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1]}]
```

Inset Json Data in Table :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("/SuperAdmin/Image/GetAllImageList",
                function (json) {
                    cache: false;
                    var tr;
                    //Append each row to html table
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        var serialNum = i + 1; 
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + serialNum + "</td>"); 
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].ID + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Image_Name + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].ImageInByte + "</td>");
                        $('#MydataTable').append(tr);
                        serialNum++; //increment serialNum 
                        $(document).ready(Datatable_show); //Call DataTable 
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

here are couple of ideas you could explore.

1. Send single image to browser.

   return File(ImageInbyte, "image/jpeg", Image_Name + "_" + ID + ".jpeg");
2. Convert byte array to file and send it via Memory stream.

   using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(ImageInbyte))
      {
         return Image.FromStream(mStream);
      }
3. Convert byte array to file and than to base64 encoded image and send to browser.

   Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)ImageInbyte.Length);
   string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   string imageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;

I hope this can guide you into resolving your problem.

Cheers

Comment: @Bukovich Json return all image list from the controller and how can I convert ImageInbyte in client-side. can you please share in detail.thanks

Comment: You cannot convert byte array on client side to image, you need to send it as relative file path on server and let the web server "do the work" on sending the file to the web browser OR you need to have the image converted to base64 encoded string image. Please, note that if you have really long list of images it could take very long time to send all images via base64 encoded strings.

Comment: From your question I could assume that you are having all images stored into some sort of database, is that right?

Comment: Which way you want to go?

Comment: Any way you want, I just view the list of the image in the client-side and this code returns the JSON result.

Comment: What returns _imageManager.GetAll() ?

Comment: image list from database

Comment: public List<ImageFile> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Images.OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToList();
        }

Comment: Whats the order of the list?

Comment: this is the query, data will  show  ascending or descending order formate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can part from here this is only example code rewrite for your own suite. That's NOT FULLY FUNCTIONAL just an idea.

```
string jsonReply = "{";

foreach (ImageFile image in allImage_List)
{
  Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)image.Item3.Length); 
  string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
  string imageBase64= "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;

  jsonReply += "[\"id\": " + image.Item1 + ", \"name\": " + image.Item2 + "\"image\": 
           " + imageBase64 + "],";
}

jsonReply = jsonReply.TrimEnd(',');
jsonReply += "}";

return new JsonResult(jsonReply);
```

Than you need to loop in jQuery and use as it fits your purposes. Yet again I remind you that if you have long image list it will suffer strong performance penalties and long loading time. As in general base64 encoded images could go to really long strings to transfer.

I would naturally prefer to remove the images from database store and save them as physical files on the hard drive and store the image path and file name into the database. But that would be whole another story requiring to change your application logic for image storage.

On this stage maybe you should stick with the base64 encoded images and send them as strings, considering as bottleneck for your app.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Post Scriptum: I forgot to advert you about the base64 js escape for special symbols which you might run into. Just add additional method to JavaScript Encode the base64 string. HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode